# Are there any calculations involved for designing pulse jets?

Tags: jet-engine, jet

Are there any requirements for calculations to determine things like exhaust length, combustion chamber size, etc? Also, does the end of the combustion chamber need to be a semi-sphere, or can it be flat?

Comment: Do you think it is remotely possible that the answer to the question is, *"No, there are **no** calculations involved in designing pulse jets; they just guess at everything"*?  Of course the answer is: *"Yes, Aeronautical design is a math-intensive, rigorous subject"*

Comment: Do you think it is possible to answer a question, no matter how dumb it may seem to you, politely? Or is this beyond your scope of ability?

Comment: Here you have something of interest: https://aardvark.co.nz/pjet/inside_pj.pdf

Comment: Thanks- I did find this calculator excel spreadsheet, which seems to answer my question. Now it's just finding the materials. :)

Comment: You can adjust the resonance frequency with the length of the jet using [this formula](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-5/Open-End-Air-Columns). For the simplest pulse jets check out [Colin Furze](http://www.colinfurze.com/big-pulse-jet-project.html). This guy is not completely serious, but a genius nonetheless.

Comment: I'm reading that now- thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**YES**

There are calculations involved in the *design* of a pulse jet. (title question)

**YES**

There are requirements for calculations... (first body question)

**NO**

The end of the combustion chamber does not *need* to be a hemi-sphere. (second body question)

Comment: This may not actually be correct - chances are that if you had a fair sense of what a pulse jet should be, you could put together something via the "that looks about right" method which would sustain operation and produce thrust.  It wouldn't be ideal, but there's a fair chance it would work, or could be refined to by experiment without any calculation at all.  However, that is not the usual approach.  You can design airplanes by similar methods - they often fly, but you might not want to be on board when they do so.